# Repository in .NET webforms database connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, webforms

I'm trying to implement a repository in my project and I'm following this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535781/10419620.

Here's the code:

The interface:

```
namespace FolhaRegisto.Database.Repositories
{
    public interface IRepository<TEntity>
    {
        List<TEntity> FetchAll();
        IQueryable<TEntity> Query { get; }
        void Add(TEntity entity);
        void Delete(TEntity entity);
        void Save();
    }
}
```

and the class

```
namespace FolhaRegisto.Database.Repositories
{
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        DataContext db;

        public Repository(DataContext db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Query
        {
            get { return db.GetTable<T>(); }
        }

        public List<T> FetchAll()
        {
            return Query.ToList();
        }

        public void Add(T entity)
        {
            db.GetTable<T>().InsertOnSubmit(entity);
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            db.GetTable<T>().DeleteOnSubmit(entity);
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find anything explicit for Web Forms. I think I understand how it works but I still don't know how do i provide a connection string to the `DataContext`. I created a Linq to SQL class and selected tables, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: And whaе are you expected? Should we write code for you? Try to read some articles, tutorials to find out more about it

Comment: I did except it's all for MVC

Comment: If the question is How to pass connection string to DataContext then you need to add it to config file. You can find it in Microsoft docs.

Comment: A different approach (i.e. not this repository pattern) is recommended for WebForms. It is because Microsoft originally developed data access for WebForms in a different way. Although older and theoretically inferior, it has very wide support in Visual Studio so it is a pleasure to use it. In short: You can connect you user interface to database by clicking in Visual Studio. These repository classes are not needed. I recommend to read a book about WebForms. :-)

Comment: I assume you mean I can use entity framework for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for whoever feels lost in this topic like me. I think what you are looking for is Model-Binding in Webforms.

Here's the tutorial I managed to find that explains clearly everything in detail.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/retrieving-data

Very good!